Long, sideways table without using lscape
I am trying to create a sideways table to span over multiple pages, but without using the lscape package. The reason for this is, I do not want either the header or footer on my document to also be rotated, nor the actual page on the pdf to be rotated. This is achieved with the rotating package by using a sideways table environment,
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\lhead{A header}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{A sideways table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e & f
\hline
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}

which is incompatible with the longtable package :(
Is there any way to achieve this?

Welcome to TeX.SE! sidewaystable is intended for one page long table. For long tables you need landscape environment (provided by lscape or pdflscape packages).

Regarding page headers and footers the sidewaystable and landscape environments behavior on the same way: page header and footer ore not rotated.

Thank you! Of course you are right and I realised my mistake very soon after posting the question... :-)


I do not want either the header or footer on my document to also be rotated, nor the actual page on the pdf to be rotated.

There seems to be some confusion over what the landscape environment does. For sure, it does not rotate the header and footer lines relative to their standard, or portrait-mode, locations. Instead, within a landscape envrionment the table (or longtable) gets rotated -- as one would expect. And, when viewing the pdf file in most (all?) pdf browser, the whole page gets rotated as well, so that readers don't have to crane their necks in order to read the table's contents. Most readers actually find this to very convenient.
To confirm these claims, just look the following 2-page spread that results from printing the pdf file on sheets of paper. Happily, the headers are at the top, the page numbers are at the right-hand edge of the footer lines, and it is indeed only the longtable that's been rotated -- because it occurs in a landscape environment.

\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % for 'fancy' page style
\lhead{A header}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

%% headers and footers

\caption{A landscape table} \\
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\[1ex]
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\hline 
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{\footnotesize cont'd on next page}
\\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h  \\

\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}


Thank you Mico, indeed just after posting this question I noticed the same, and couldn't find how to delete it!
